# Is a custom URI scheme allowed to use the hash/pound sign (#) for it's content?

Tags: android, url, uri

At Kullo we use addresses in the format `username#domain.tld` (e.g. `hi#kullo.net`) where `#` is a constant, similar to the `@` in email addresses.

Now what would be a correct URI format that is designed to send a message to a given address:

`kullo:username#domain.tld` or `kullo:username%23domain.tld`?

The first one is to be preferred because it's simplicity. But given the rules of an URI, am I allowed to make the `#` something else than a fragment separator for my custom scheme `kullo`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986), the hash sign is reserved but that doesn't mean that a custom URI scheme must use it as a separator:

> 2.2.  Reserved Characters
>
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> [...]
>
> Thus, characters in the reserved set are protected from
> normalization and are therefore safe to be used by scheme-specific
> and producer-specific algorithms for delimiting data subcomponents
> within a URI.
>
> [...]
>
> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> no delimiting role is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII.

So you can decide to not escape it, but you will lose the normalization functionality:

```
kullo:username#domain.tld != kullo:username%23domain.tld
```

but

```
kullo:username#domain.tld == kullo:%75sername#domain.tld
```